# Usual Tauberian theorem for Laplace transform

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I would like a precision concerning the Tauberian theorem for the Laplace transform. Actually the statement is not clear to me and depends on the books. Assume we have a function $f : (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{C}.$ And assume that $f \in o(t^{-\alpha})$ with $\alpha<1$ for $t\to 0^+$. (This is enough for the integrability at $0$.) Then $$z \mapsto \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-zt} f(t)dt$$ is in $o(???)$ when $|z|\to +\infty.$ What should I put instead of ??? In some books I found $|z|^{\alpha}$ in other $|z|^{\alpha+1}.$ Thanks for any help.

PS : We, of course, assume that there is at least one $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that this integral exists. Moreover, by the standard theory we know that it exists on a halfplane. I let $|z|$ go to infinity in this halfplane.

PS2 : I would like to have a reversible condition. That is, if $F$ is holomorphic on the halfplane and $F\in o(???)$ when $|z|\to +\infty$ then $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F) \in o(t^{-\alpha})$ when $t\to 0^+.$

Answer (score 0):

No Tauberian theorem here.

If $f\in L^1(0,\infty)$ and $|f(t)| \le C t^{-a}$ as $t \to 0$  for some $a \in (0,1)$

then $|\int_b^\infty e^{-xt}f(t)dt| \le \|f\|_{L^1}e^{-bx}$ and $|\int_0^b f(t) e^{-xt} dt| \le C \int_0^b t^{-a}dt = C \frac{b^{1-a}}{1-a}$.

Letting $b = (1-a)\frac{\log x}{x}$ you get $$|\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-xt}dt| \le x^{a-1}(\|f\|_{L^1} + C \frac{((1-a)\log x)^{1-a}}{1-a})$$

Comment: I don't see what is your conclusion here. Are you proving that $f \in O(t^{-\alpha})$ implies $\mathcal{L}(f) \in O(|z|^{\alpha-1})$ ?

Comment: @Noether No, I'm proving what I wrote, ie. $o(\Re(z)^{a-1+\epsilon})$

Comment: Ok but note that I didn't assume that $f$ was in $L^1(0,+\infty)$. I just assume a condition at the origin and that there is at least one $z$ such that the laplace transform exists. (And then we know that it exists on a halfplane.)

Comment: @Noether Thus you did assume $f(t) e^{-x_0 t}1_{t > 0}$ is $L^1$.

Comment: And if you only assume some antiderivative of $f(t) e^{-x_0 t}$ is $L^1$ it doesn't change a lot